# How to open pdf in separate window for custom links in Magento?

Tags: magento, pdf

I need to set one static page and list of links and by clicking on that link, pdf file for that link should be opened in new window.

Each link contains it's own pdf file

I tried to search for that no able to find any related result

So Please anyone help me to do that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Using Magento CMS, you can create the static page.

2) When Creating Links, add attrbute "target" as "_blank" in href tags.

Ex: `<a href="LINK_TO_THE_FILE" target="_blank"> LINK TEXT </a>`

Comment: but main question is separate pdf click on link

Comment: pdf  how to call for each link clicked? edit your answer please

Comment: How you uploaded the pdf files to magento. Are you using any extensions?